# Web Api : Sending XML request through POSTMAN always gives null object

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, postman, datacontract

I am using Postman extension and trying to send **Xml post request** to my web api.

**Sample Model:**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Employee
{

        [DataMember]
        [Range(10000, 99999)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Postman Request:**
[image]

While executing request I am always getting **null employee object** in **post method** of my controller.

If I send **JSON** request then it works fine.

I also tried providing namespace in DataContract attribute but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you had, but I setup my class as below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The data from the XML is automatically mapped straight onto your Employee class.

What my problem was, that XML is case sensitive.  Make absolutely sure all your XML parameters names, match your class parameters.  It takes just one parameter to be wrong and the whole request will be null.  Check the debug log tree under the request object is you see the following error (you have to search for it, but its there):

```
Incorrect Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

If you see that then there is a parameter that is not correct.  Send the request parameter, by parameter, until you find the parameter that is wrong.

As for serializing from and to XML make sure the startup.cs only has the following code:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

In your controller set the annotation at the top above your class to:

```
[Produces("application/XML")]
```

and on your route method set it to:

```
[Consumes("application/XML")]
```

Sadly I lost a day and half on this issue.  This link was useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding

What's even more soul destroying is that others are also encountering the same issue.  However, they have solved it, but not had the courtesy to tell others.

Tip: Try using free version of SoapUI, it has a few more features that really help with debugging.